# Possible to hook into the phone calling functions with current iPhone SDK?

Tags: iphone, nstimer, phone-call

I've heard it mentioned elsewhere, one cannot programmatically hook into the phone call area of an iPhone using the current SDK. I'm looking to learn iPhone development and Obj C, with the end goal of creating a call timer app that runs in the background and alerts the user when a call has gone on too long.

Is it even possible to hook into methods liek that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Your app will be interrupted when the user receives a call, and your code will not be allowed to run while the user is on the call. Additionally, there are no background apps allowed for the iphone. The best you can get is push notification, but you can't create a daemon or anything like that.

This information is provided in the [iPhone Application Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ApplicationEnvironment/ApplicationEnvironment.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW14)

Comment: Thanks for spedy reply. Bit of a bummer - I was wondering why there were no call timing apps available :(

Perhaps there is another way to approach it?

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately this is the design decision Apple went with in order to get some extra levels of security. They were probably worried that someone would write an app that listened in on calls or something to that effect. Welcome to the restricted world of iPhone development. You can do a lot with the iPhone, but you learn quickly there are walls everywhere :)

Answer (score 0):

With version 4 you can now multitask to some degree.