# Is it possible for me to control the iPhone calls?

Tags: iphone

I'm developing a call program in a iOS application. This is intended for personal use, not for the App store. I would like to control iPhone app to call someone, receive calls and disconnect calls whenever I need. Is it possible for me to control iPhone calls? If it's possible, what API can I use？ Please name some.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Possible to hook into the phone calling functions with current iPhone SDK?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1518394/possible-to-hook-into-the-phone-calling-functions-with-current-iphone-sdk)

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible via the iOS SDK.

(I don't know if there are any solutions for jailbroken devices.)

Comment: After searching on the internet,I find the problem could only be solved by searching iOS's low-level device-driver communication releated.Is the way right?If yes, how could I find the reference about iPhone low-level driver,I can't find any on the web.

Comment: Is the CoreTelephony.framework can solve this problem? CTCall Class Reference:https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CTCall/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009590. thank you!